# Need regex for range values

Tags: javascript, regex

Need regex for following combination.

- Only Numbers
- Max 2 digit after decimal
- following types of range available

  - `5`
  - `8.95`
  - `>2.5`
  - `<5.65`
  - `>=4.24`
  - `<=7.2`
  - `1.2-3.2`

i tried below regex which accept number, two decimal no and should not end with <>=. special characters.

`/^(?!.*<>=.$)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/gm`

Need regex for range values

Comment: i have added more explanation and what i have tried.

Comment: Can you have `>=4.24-3.2`?

Comment: >=4.24 - 3.2 No we cant have.

Comment: Perhaps like `^(?:(?:[<>]=?)?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?-\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$` https://regex101.com/r/6bzGE9/1

Comment: this is ^(?:(?:[<>]=?)?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?-\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$ working as expected. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either a single occurrence of a number preceded by a combination of `<>=` or match 2 numbers with a hyphen in between.

```
^(?:(?:[<>]=?)?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?-\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `(?:[<>]=?)?` Optionally match `<` `>` `<=` `>=`
  - `\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Match 1+ digits with optional decimal part of 1-2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?-\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Match a digits format with a hyphen in between
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bzGE9/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?:(?:[<>]=?)?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?-\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/;
[
  "5",
  "8.95",
  ">2.5",
  "<5.65",
  ">=4.24",
  "<=7.2",
  "1.2-3.2",
  "1-1.3",
  "1-4",
  ">2",
  ">=4",
  "2.5>",
  "1.123"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} ==> ${pattern.test(s)}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex does what you ask for. The test has first some matches, followed by non-matches:

```js
const regex = /^(([><]=?)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/;
[
  '1',
  '12',
  '12.2',
  '12.34',
  '>1.2',
  '>=1.2',
  '<1.2',
  '<=1.2',
  '1.2-3.4',
  '1.22-3.44',
  'x1',
  '1.234',
  '1.222-3.444'
].forEach((str) => {
  let result = regex.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + result)
})
```

Output:

```
1 ==> true
12 ==> true
12.2 ==> true
12.34 ==> true
>1.2 ==> true
>=1.2 ==> true
<1.2 ==> true
<=1.2 ==> true
1.2-3.4 ==> true
1.22-3.44 ==> true
x1 ==> false
1.234 ==> false
1.222-3.444 ==> false
```

Comment: @Roshan Patil: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?